# Laptop cooling fan making a griding noise at low temperatures

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

When I use my laptop while the A/C is on (temperature around 27-28), the fan starts making a grinding noise. This does not happen when the temperatures are high. Further, the CPU's temperatures are around 45-55 when idle.

What I am thinking is that at low temperatures, the fan begins to rotate at a particular speed that causes it to make this noise. When the temperature increases, the noise disappears because the fan starts spinning more rapidly. Some sort of resonance issue, but I may be dead-wrong.

Any suggestions? I took the laptop to the service center but the fan failed me there (made no noise). They simply got rid of the dust in my computer and gave it back to me.

Comment: Replace the fan to rule this out. If a new fan works across all usage (idle and heavy use) then it'll have been a bad bearing or dust.

Comment: The laptop is still under warranty. How do I convince them? The service guys are lazy, and won't check the fan for bearing problems.

Comment: Persist. Complain higher up if necessary. The fan wasn't making the noise whn you first bought it and it shouldn't be making the noise if it's still under warranty - they should fix or replace it if you can provide evidence it makes the noise. Take a video and include the serial number in the footage to give them the best evidence. Or ask them to have it for a number of days (they may still give it back saying nothing wrong) - this is where you can build your own case against their response.

Comment: I am making a video of it. Will visit the center tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Grinding noise means fan touches a wire.

Comment: temperatures may also affect the bearing oil or even dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fan is going bad, You only have a few options but the best thing to do is bypass the middle men with the company either find their corporate phone number thats usually best if not then ask for a manager. Corporate usually will put the screws to the people to get the job done right so they dont get bad reviews.

If all else fails post bad reviews EVERYWHERE Yelp, Angieslist, Facebook, Twitter etc after they notice they might change there mind about not fixing your laptop.

For others that are Not under warranty:
 -Best to replace the fan
 -Clean the fan out as best you can with Canned compressed air
 -Buy an external laptop fan (not a great option but may buy you some extra life if you cant replace the internal fan)

Comment: If the laptop is still under warranty I wouldn't be recommending people void their warranties with suggestions to replace parts... but, yes, the advice given is, ultimately, right :)

Comment: Edited, he didnt say before it was under warranty

Comment: No problem - good answer though :)

Comment: Though how others might run into this question that aren't under warranty so i put back my other answer and also another incase they refuse to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

the fan is starting to go bad or there is something stuck in it that all the blades are hitting as it spins, the fact that its only happening on low speed and not high speed makes me think maybe its a baring... you can do a custom fan curve to turn the fan off at low temps and make it go straight to 100% for high temps. even curve it from 105-150% if your hardware supports it for the highest temps but the only way to get rid of the noise aside from changing the fan or heatsink assembly (if the fans are soldered to the heatsink you'll need to change the entire assembly) is going from 0-100% on a custom curve and just stop the fans from running in the problematic range

you can lower it by 5% until the noise starts (N) then crank it back up 5% and go from 0% on cold to N+5% if you don't want to go from 0-100%

also you can try to see if lower than the default 30% on cold will make the noise go away too. drop it 5% from default till the noise goes away but i have a striking suspicion it won't go away till 0%

having your fan off when the CPU is cold will not harm it and then having it go right to 100% isn't good for the life of a new fan but it seems your fan is already dying anyway so this is to increase the life of a dying part and is ok

p.s. changing thermal paste got me -10c, a cooling stand got me -5c and blowing a fan at the laptop got me an other -10c
all together it adds up on a laptop. right now a further 10 degrees would have me in my sweet spot anyone who says 10c wouldn't make a difference probably hasn't owned many laptops

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).